# Сохранение файла при помощи SaveFileDialog на Vasual Basic 2010

Tags: visual-basic

Доброго времени суток. У меня возникла такая проблема: нужно сделать сохранение файлов таким образом, чтобы выбранный файл автоматически сохранялся в определенную папку (в моем случае "Photo"). Но у меня не получается... 
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Непонятно .з.

Если папка определена и файл - диалога и не надо, сохраняйте так. Или в диалоге надо показать определённую папку? InitialDirectory в помощь... И что из этого не получается?

Comment: Ну, мне нужно было при помощи SaveFileDialog выбирать файл, и при нажатии кнопки "Сохранить" файл должен копироваться в папку рядом с экзешником.  
InitialDirectory пробовал, но наверное не там я его пишу(либо путь не правильно указываю)
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = ("\Photo")

Comment: Там надо задать полный путь - который можно добыть, по-моему, из Application.StartupPath

Comment: Никогда не использовал... Вы не могли бы дать пример использования Application.StartupPath? Буду весьма благодарен

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx - в мсдн есть примеры практически на всё)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос отменяется, сделал по другому, в две кнопки - одна открывает для пред просмотра, вторая сохраняет:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Изображение (*.jpg)|*.jpg| Изображение (*.gif)|*.gif "
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = CType _
           (saveFileDialog1.OpenFile(), System.IO.FileStream)

        Select Case saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex

            Case 1
                Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(fs, _
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

            Case 2
                Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(fs, _
                   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        End Select

        fs.Close()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Все файлы (*.*)|*.*"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Правда, так как я хотел не получилось... Ну да не страшно ;)